# Get first two characters of text field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a text field X where User can write a long or a short string. In an other text field Y, I need to get the first two caracters of that field X. I don't want to do this with JS since it will not be executed if a record is created with import. Is there any way to do this without using c# plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not sure what code you have now, but what events do you have for the textfield the user is typing in?

Comment: I don't have any js code for that since I've already found that js code will not be usefull in import, so I am looking for a way to do this without js. A plugin can do that well in normal creation and import but I dont' want to use plugins.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Fill a second textbox with the two characters or fill some data with the first two chars?

Comment: I have a text field X: The user can write for example: 123456.. or abcd... I want to initialise the other text field Y with : 12 or ab

Comment: from a dynamics crm import perspective, not possible, you either need a plugin/custom workflow that does the job.

Comment: I'd like to do this with a workflow but I don't find any way to get the two first characteres of a text field, do you have any idea about this plz?

Comment: custom code: plugin or a custom workflow activity to take the first 2 chars

Answer (score 4):

You will need to either use either a plugin or custom workflow activity for this.

Luckily,  Gap Consulting provide a custom workflow activity which should hopefully suit this.

Download and install [Gap Consulting Workflow Essentials](http://www.gapconsulting.co.uk/essentials/workflow-essentials/) (it's free).

Create a workflow and then use the custom workflow activity, Gap String Functions > Gap.StringFunctions.SubString.

Inputs:

- Text: Field X
- From Left to Right: True
- Start Index: 0
- Length: 2.

You can then copy the output from that into field Y.

*Full discloure; I work for Gap Consulting*

Answer (score 1):

[Manipulation Library](https://manipulationlibrary.codeplex.com/) can help you too for CRM 2011.

You should pick the method **ManipulationLibrary.Strings.Substring.**
Its use is exactly the same as James Wood describes for his tool.

Inputs:

- Text: Input field
- From Left to Right: True
- Start Index: 0
- Length: 2